# Custom Exception-Java

Tags: java, exception

Well, i'm programming a rent car system with clients and these have an id card. At the time of renting the car the client needs to identify himself with the id, so I need a custom exception that handles if the input of the user is 8 numbers and one letter, e.g.:

```
55550000A
```

I've already made an exception for if the input is int or not and it goes:

```
   import java.util.*;
   import java.util.Scanner;
public class read {
static Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);
public static int readInt() {
    int num = 0;
    boolean loop = true;

    while (loop) {
        try {
            num = leer.nextInt();
            loop = false;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid value!");
            System.out.println("Write again");
    leer.next();
         } 
      }
    return num;
  }
}
```

The only thing you have to do is declare the variable and call the method like this:

```
int variable=read.readInt();
```

So it would be good if the id could work like that, I mean another method readId() which would return the value. The thing is that i don't know how to make an exception for a custom format or if this is even possible so any help will be helpful. Thank you very much!

Comment: JavaScript has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: you didn't create any custom exception and also you didn't validate input

Comment: And what exactly is your problem? Meaning: I don't see a custom exception in your code; and I don't see any specific checking on the format. 
Minor hint: calling a class `read` is a bad idea; according to the common Java naming conventions, classes always start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: When you are dealing with validation it is not an exceptional behaviour for the `thing` being checked to not pass the test, it would probably be an exceptional behaviour if `thing` is not there at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was a little confusive but I guess you want to create a new exception.

Create a file MyAppException.java

```
class MyAppException extends Exception {

private String message = null;

public MyAppException() {
    super();
}

public MyAppException(String message) {
    super(message);
    this.message = message;
}
}
```

You can throw it via

```
throw new MyAppException();
```

But I guess an exception is not needed for what you want:

```
public static String readId() {
    String id = "";
    while(true){
        id = leer.next();
        try{
            Integer.parseInt(id.substring(0,8));
        }catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
            continue;
        }
        if(id.length() != 9)continue;
        if(Character.isLetter(id.chatAt(8)))break;
    }
    return id;
}
```

Comment: You have a mis-spelling in your answer:  if(Character.isLetter(d.charAt(8)))break;

Comment: Yeah, I should have only asked how to check if a string have an specific format :) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @evan and uw Supersoaker

Answer (score 0):

@epascarello is correct, other than the Java in their names, they are both very different, as for the question, try to make a custom exception like this:

```
public class InputMismatchException extends Exception {
    public InputMismatchException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you only want to throw exceptions to prevent some kind of error from causing your program to completely fail in some form. A **better** solution would be to validate input before it is used later in the program. Create conditions that check if the input is the desired length and data type, if it is not, you need to get the input again.
Using exceptions excessively points to bad design and the potential for serious problems if the code is modified later on.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own exception by extending `Exception` -

```
class InvalidIdException extends Exception
{
      public InvalidIdException() {}

      public InvalidIdException(String message)
      {
         super(message);
      }
 }
```

And from your client class check whether the input id is valid or not. If it is an invalid id then `throw` the `InvalidIdException`. Suppose your are validating your id in the `validateId()` method. Then you can throw an `InvalidIdException` from this method -

```
boolean isValidId(String id) throws InvalidIdException{

    if(id == null){
            throw new InvalidIdException("Id is null");
        }
   else {
    //check for id formatting 
    //for example whether id has it's minimum length
    //contains any character etc.
    throw new InvalidIdException("Id has wrong format");
   }

   return true;
}
```